The GDB Debugger built into Qt-Creator is not functioning properly, throwing out an assert from "setTokenBarrier()" & not displaying function chains
This popped up recently.
For no discernable reason, the debugger is no longer running properly in QtCreator.
I couldnt find the chain of functions window, and when I checked the terminal output, I noticed every time I was running it, an QTC_ASSERT was firing:
SOFT ASSERT [02:09:50.629]: "good" in /home/anon/Library/qt-creator/src/plugins/debugger/gdb/gdbengine.cpp:2057

I even went through the trouble of rebuilding Qt-Creator.
Good news is though, that as I was making this question, I discovered the answer, which I will post below just so someone else doesnt have to waste 4 hours figuring this out.


What actually happened is that the layout got changed and it appeared as if the modules were simply not loading. While it looked like an error, everything was actually fixed when I right clicked the tabs of breakpoints, and just reset it to the default layout.
